# Completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a Hausdorff space X with respect to the dirac measure.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, outer-measure, hausdorff-measure

Should I do this by constructing an outer measure from the Dirac measure and extend the space into a collection of sets that follow the Caratheodory's condition and state the completion using Caratheodory's theorem by restricting the outer measure to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra? What is the role of X being Hausdorff in the problem?

Comment: It's much simpler than that.  The completion of a $\sigma$-algebra with respect to a measure is all sets of the form $B \triangle N$, where $B$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra and $N$ is null (i.e. a subset of a measure zero set), and $\triangle$ is symmetric difference.  But for the Dirac measure, what exactly are the null sets?

Comment: Or more simply, what is the smallest (indeed, the only) $\sigma$-algebra containing all the null sets?

Comment: So I just take all the elements of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on X and the null sets under the dirac measure. Take their symmetric difference and that's the completion already? Regarding what's a null set wrt the dirac measure, my guess is any set which an element x is not in the set, by the definition of the measure? I'm not really sure

Comment: Yes, exactly, any set not containing $x$ is a null set, since it's contained in $X \setminus \{x\}$ which is a Borel set of measure zero.  What sets can you get by taking the symmetric difference of such a set with either $\emptyset$ or $\{x\}$?

Comment: (By the way, this is where we use the Hausdorff property: it ensures that the set $\{x\}$ is closed and in particular Borel.)

Comment: That would be just the union of two disjoint sets, right? The closed neighborhood of an element x in a Hausdorff space is {x} if i remember correctly.

Comment: The point I am trying to lead you toward is that the completion is the set of **all** subsets of $X$, i.e. the power set.  **Every** subset of $X$ can be written as the symmetric difference of a null set and a Borel set.  Now try to prove this.

Comment: Oh this is nice. Will try to do this. Thank you so much

Comment: So what you are saying is that {x} is a Borel set right, so, it is now easy to show that any subset of X can be generated by the symmetric difference of the Borel sets and null sets in X with respect to the dirac measure.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Thank you for the help!